# Im facing an AttributeError

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.x

Please guys help me I'm new here and today i tried to code something using date and time. I had 2 errors i cant fix.

1

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now() 

Attributeerror: "module" object has no attribute "now".
```

2

```
import datetime
currentDate = datetime.datetime.today() 

Attributeerror: "module" object has no attribute "today".
```

I have absolutely no idea where the error can be. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you you call your script `datetime.py` by any chance?

Comment: Is there any local module called "datetime" in your project? this may be a module name conflict issue.

Comment: Im pretty sure, i just have some comments in slovak language behind the code.

Comment: You should *always* post the full traceback. The traceback would tell us in an instance if you have made the classic mistake of naming your script `datetime`, so that it is imported instead of the standard library module.

Comment: Yeah i called. Thanks man sry im just a newbie..

Comment: didnt know i cant call my file datetime.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably named your script `datetime.py`, or have such a script in the same directory still.

Your traceback probably looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "datetime.py", line 1, in <module>
    import datetime
  File "/Users/mj/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-3.4/datetime.py", line 2, in <module>
    now = datetime.datetime.now() 
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'now'
```

Note that the first file and the second file *are the exact same files*. Instead of the standard library, you are importing your own script again, and that script has a name `datetime` that is a reference to itself.

Since your own script has no `now` or `today` names defined, you get an error.

Rename or remove the script; make sure you remove the `datetime.pyc` file as well, to fix this.

Comment: yeah thanks man i just now renamed the file (based on your comments)

Comment: im new here, didnt know i cant name the file datetime.py :D sorry im newbie